# Неопределённое поведение в недостижимом коде

Tags: c++, неопределённое-поведение

Содержит ли следующий код `UB` или надо вызвать функцию для этого?

```
int foo() {
   int a = 2 + 3;
   // no return
}

int main() {
   // foo();
}
```

Comment: Конечно нужно, а что не работает?

Comment: Что такое `UB`?

Comment: @Dimabytes то есть код корректный?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия неопределённое поведение

Comment: За что минус???

Comment: А какое, вам кажется, тут вообще может быть неопределенное поведение? В чем?

Comment: @Harry ну если будет вызов функции, то это `UB` по стандарту. А меня интересует, будет ли оно без вызова. Собственно, ответ на ваш вопрос мне и нужен

Comment: Ну какое *поведение* без поведения? :)

Comment: @ИмяФамилия неопределённое поведение (undefined behavior) (название вопроса посмотрите)

Comment: Если кого-то интересует мое мнение :), то нет поведения - нет и неопределенности. Без вызова никакого UB нет.

Answer (score 10):

Нет здесь никакого неопределенного поведения.

У UB бывает два вида причин:

1. Времени компиляции. (Например, [использование зарезервированного идетификатора](http://eel.is/c++draft/reserved.names#2).)
2. Времени выполнения. (Например целочисленное деление на ноль.)

Во втором случае, чтобы поведение стало неопределенным, **выполнение должно достичь**<sup>1</sup> **какого-то участка кода**, про который в стандарте написано, что он вызывает неопределенное поведение (или его поведение не описано вообще). (см [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23153445/2752075) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18385020/2752075) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48210052/2752075))

У нас второй случай:

> [**[stmt.return]/2**](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2)
>
> Flowing off the end of a ... function with a cv `void` return type is equivalent to a `return` with no operand. Otherwise **flowing off the end of a function** ... results in undefined behavior.

<sup>(выделение добавлено мной)</sup>

Написано, *"если выполнение выходит из функции..."*, т.е. во время выполнения. Если бы речь шла о времени компиляции, то так и написали бы: *"если любой возможный путь выполнения функции всегда достигает ее конца..."*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Точнее, UB появляется когда выполнение вызывающего его кода становится неизбежным.  Пример: программа может проигнорировать условие `if`-а и отказаться заходить в ветку, которая всегда вызывает UB.

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл ответ на похожий вопрос. Спасибо `LShadow77` за помощь.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23154502

> So, an unreachable statement with UB doesn't give the program UB.

Comment: не все так просто. Во-первых, проверки на достижимость или недостижимость тех или иных участков кода не регламентированы. Во-вторых, тут не "statement with UB", а отсутствие необходимого statement. В-третьих, функция не является static и даже без ее вызова в main она в обязательном порядке должна быть скомпилирована (но затем выкинута при линковке). Как компилятор должен справиться (и должен ли) с компиляцией функции, проход потока управления через которую будет завершаться UB - это еще вопрос.

Comment: @user7860670 да, поэтому у меня и возникали сомнения. Но разве ситуация по ссылке не точно такая же? Или там неверные выводы?

Comment: @user7860670 насчёт 2) и 3) согласен, не знаю влияет ли это. Насчёт 1) - в Стандарте есть "Flowing off the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a non-coroutine function with a cv void return type is equivalent to a return with no operand. Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function other than main or a coroutine ([dcl.fct.def.coroutine]) results in undefined behavior.", т.е. этот "flowing off" считается определенным чем-то

Comment: Про достижимость - это я имел ввиду "unreachable". Другими словами, раз функция имеет внешнюю линковку, то при компиляции компилятор в любом случае должен ее скомпилировать так, как будто она будет вызвана.

Comment: "[control] flowing off the end of a function" может произойти только в рантайме, поэтому никакого UB тут нет. Если бы сама компиляция компиляция функции без `return` (в одной из ветвей выполнения) вызывала UB, то так и было бы написано.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat звучит логично, но разве где-то есть разделение `UB` в Стандарте по времени его происхождения? По-моему любой `UB` является "`UB` при компиляции", т.е. компилятор генерирует "плохой код" или не генерирует вовсе. Довольно запутанно всё это, если честно)

Comment: @user7860670 согласен, но ему необязательно при этом смотреть во внутренности функции, нужен адрес только. Но это Стандарт не оговаривает, конечно, может и смотреть, так что непонятно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, но еще при компиляции кода она может производится с расчетом, что потенциального UB при работе кода не произойдет. А в этой связи могут возникнуть странности. Я имею ввиду что раз все пути (точнее единственный путь) выполнения ведут к отсутствующему return, то компилятор может счесть этот единственный путь недостижимым и начать отбрасывать выражения, а то и все тело функции и это вдруг может как-то сломать его работу.

Comment: @0x25 *"любой UB является "UB при компиляции""* Ну например `int a, b; cin >> a >> b; cout << a / b;` Во время компиляции тут UB нет. Во время выполнения оно может быть в зависимости от ввода (деление на ноль).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я имел ввиду, что при этом например может получиться неверный формат объектного файла или что-то подобное.

Comment: Ну в любом случае на английском стековерфолу консенсус, что UB в недостижимом коде не происходит. Одну ссылку вы сами привели, еще есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385020/can-code-that-will-never-be-executed-invoke-undefined-behavior и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210052/is-the-behaviour-of-a-program-that-has-undefined-behaviour-on-an-unreachable-pat

Answer (score 1):

Я склоняюсь к тому, что неопределенное поведение тут есть. Дело в том, что стандарт позволяет реализации содержать ряд допущений относительно потока исполнения:

> **6.9.2.2 Forward progress [intro.progress]**
> 1 The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one of the following:
> — (1.1) terminate,
> — (1.2) make a call to a library I/O function,
> — (1.3) perform an access through a volatile glvalue, or
> — (1.4) perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation.

То бишь, что поток исполнения в какой-то момент либо завершится, либо вызовет функцию ввода / вывода, либо произведет доступ к некоторому volatile значению или либо сделает синхронизацию или атомарную операцию. А поток исполнении в функции `foo` из примера просто обрывается, не приводя ни к чему из вышеперечисленного, подрывая допущения, которые может делать конформная реализации.

Comment: Там же есть [замечание](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#1.note-1) к приведённому вами пункту:  "This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops, even when termination cannot be proven.". То есть, насколько я понимаю, если какой-либо поток исполнения вызовет функцию `foo`, то ни один из пунктов (1.1)-(1.4) не произойдёт, а значит, компилятор имеет право выбросить вызов функции `foo`. Хотя он и так имеет право это сделать, ибо при вызове будет UB.

Comment: @wololo Главное в том, что в компилятор могут быть заложены подобные допущения. А использует ли он их для того, чтобы что-то оптимизировать, или же просто брякнется - это уже не регламентируется.

Comment: Не согласен, тут написано "любой поток" (тред), а не "любая функция". В вопросе поток один, и он не дергает `foo`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Эти допущения вполне позволяют судить о свойствах любых мест, через которые проходит поток исполнения: раз с потоком должно происходить одно из 4 вышеупомянутых действий, то и содержимое любой (ну или как минимум extern) функции должно быть таким, чтобы непременно к ним приводить. А заранее определить, что в программе создается только один главный поток и что эта функция в итоге вообще не вызывается, и проигнорировать ее содержимое компилятор не может.

Comment: Разве в приведённом вами пункте стандарта говорится, что если с потоком не произойдёт одно из четырёх вышеупомянутых действий, то поведение неопределено? Смысл этого пункта в том, чтобы дать возможность реализации удалить любой код, выполнение которого не позволило бы потоку выполнения осуществить пункты (1.1)-(1.4).

Comment: @wololo Главное в том, что в компилятор могут быть заложены подобные допущения. А использует ли он их для того, чтобы что-то оптимизировать, или же просто брякнется - это уже не регламентируется.